# Как разбить два столбца на две строки по одному id

Tags: sql

[[image: 1]

хочу чтобы таблица выглядела так: case_id 2112 id_cond 3183
case_id 2112 id cond 1935

Answer (score 1):

1. Если только разложить по `case_id` и `id_condition` - UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT 
  un.[case_id],
  un.[condition_value] AS [id_cond]
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      2712 AS [case_id],
      1711 AS [id_police],
      CONVERT([datetime], '2009-09-11', 120) AS [sign_date],
      CONVERT([datetime], '2009-09-11', 120) AS [sign_date2],
      3183 AS [id_condition],
      1935 AS [id_condition2]
  ) t
  UNPIVOT (
    [condition_value] FOR [condition_name]
    IN ([id_condition], [id_condition2])
  ) un
```

| case_id | id_cond |
| --- | --- |
| 2712 | 3183 |
| 2712 | 1935 |

2. Если надо разложить больше столбцов - CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT 
  t.[case_id],
  t.[id_police],
  c.[sign_date],
  c.[condition]
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      2712 AS [case_id],
      1711 AS [id_police],
      CONVERT([datetime], '2009-09-11', 120) AS [sign_date],
      CONVERT([datetime], '2009-09-11', 120) AS [sign_date2],
      3183 AS [id_condition],
      1935 AS [id_condition2]
  ) t
  CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
      (t.[id_condition], t.[sign_date]),
      (t.[id_condition2], t.[sign_date2])
  ) c ([condition], [sign_date])
```

| case_id | id_police | sign_date | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2712 | 1711 | 2009-09-11 00:00:00.000 | 3183 |
| 2712 | 1711 | 2009-09-11 00:00:00.000 | 1935 |

##### UPDATE:

2.1 Еще один вариант под CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT 
  t.[case_id],
  t.[id_police],
  c.[sign_date],
  c.[condition]
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      2712 AS [case_id],
      1711 AS [id_police],
      CONVERT([datetime], '2009-09-11', 120) AS [sign_date],
      CONVERT([datetime], '2009-09-11', 120) AS [sign_date2],
      3183 AS [id_condition],
      1935 AS [id_condition2]
  ) t
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      t.[id_condition] AS [condition], 
      t.[sign_date] AS [sign_date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      t.[id_condition2] AS [condition], 
      t.[sign_date2] AS [sign_date]
  ) c
```

Comment: select * from (
select
case_id,
a.id_police,
c.sign_date,
d.sign_date as sign_date2,
d.id_condition,
e.id_condition as id_condition2
from loss.tbl_Insurance_Cases a 
join loss.tbl_Occurrences b on a.occurr_id = b.occurr_id
join tbl_policies c on a.id_police = c.id_police
left join tbl_Agreements d on a.id_police  = d.id_police
left join tbl_InsuranceConditions e on c.id_conditions = e.id_condition
) t CROSS APPLY (
values 
(t.id_condition, t.sign_date),
(t.id_condition2, t.sign_date2)
) c (condition, sign_date)

Comment: ругается на values

Comment: можешь подсказать, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Данный пример работает на SQL Server. Уточни какая СУБД, от этого решение вопроса может быть совсем другим.